# Serialize List<T> property when is null or Count = 0

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have this classes:

```
    public class EncuestaRespuesta
    {
        public string idCaso { get; set; }
        public string tipoEncuesta { get; set; }
        public string codMovimiento { get; set; }
        public string motivoRetirada { get; set; }
        public string duracion { get; set; }
        public DateTime fechaHora { get; set; }
        public string gestor { get; set; }
        public List<RespuestasEncuesta> listRespuestasEncuestas { get; set;}
    }

    public class RespuestasEncuesta
    {
        public string pregunta { get; set; }
        public string respuesta { get; set; }
        public string numOrdenTrabajo { get; set; }
    }
```

The *List* `listRespuestasEncuestas`  is **null** or **Count = 0**

Using JSON.NET,

```
    // https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };

    settings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter()); // "fechaHora": "2018-02-23T12:42:52.4456475+01:00",

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

the result:

```
{
  "idCaso": "5009E000007Hp94QAC",
  "tipoEncuesta": "T3_1018_RM",
  "codMovimiento": "1",
  "motivoRetirada": "2",
  "duracion": "0",
  "fechaHora": "2018-03-20T09:18:00",
  "gestor": null,
  "listRespuestasEncuestas": []
}
```

I would like this JSON string:

```
{
  "idCaso": "5009E000007Hp94QAC",
  "codMovimiento": "1",
  "motivoRetirada": "1",
  "duracion": "",
  "fechaHora": "2018-02-06T14:40:43.511Z",
  "gestor": "",
  "tipoEncuesta": "T3_1018_RM",
  "listRespuestasEncuestas": [
    {
      "numOrdenTrabajo": "",
      "pregunta": "",
      "respuesta": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to add a blank item to the list, it's not a null list, the item has null values.

Comment: Your JSON represents a list with one element, which is completly different from the value "null"

Comment: The list is **null** or **Count = 0**, is required serialize like one blank item.

Comment: @Kiquenet That is very peculiar. What happens when you deserialize it back? You will have a list with one item.

Comment: @Rotem The Json string I send to external REST Service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [serialization callbacks](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) in Json.NET to fake an empty value when serializing a null or empty list.

e.g.

```
[OnSerializing]
void OnSerializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
    if (listRespuestasEncuestas == null)
    {
        listRespuestasEncuestas = new List<RespuestasEncuesta>();
    }
    if (!listRespuestasEncuestas.Any())
    {
        //Add an empty item to the list.
    }
}

[OnSerialized]
void OnSerializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
    //if the list contains a single empty item, remove it and return the list to either empty or null.
}

[OnDeserialized]
void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
    //What to do if we receive a list with a single empty item? Do you want to keep it? Decide here.
}
```

It should be said though that this is a very unconventional requirement and it is hard to see any value in implementing it.